# Opening Window With Second Thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I'm opening my next Window using the below code as it's running on another thread to the UI thread. I'm getting a `'Initialization of 'System.Windows.Controls.X' threw an exception.'...` but when I call the next Window back in the UI thread I don't receive the error. How do I get over calling a Window from another thread?

```
Page2 page2 = new Page2();
App.Current.MainWindow = page2;
this.SimpleInvoke(() => this.Close());
this.SimpleInvoke(() => page2.Show());

public static class DispatcherObjectExtensions
{
    public static void SimpleInvoke(this DispatcherObject dispatcherObject, Action action)
    {
        dispatcherObject.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,               (ThreadStart)delegate()
{
       // in the gui thread here, so do what you gotta do
});
```